# How do I ssh into a aws web server with a .pem key?

Tags: ssh, terminal, pem

I am on a MAC and open terminal, I know how to log into ssh with the command ssh root@domain.com

However this web server sent me a .pem key to use as the password.

Normally I just enter the password and get in.

I have no idea and can't find any help online that makes sense to me as I don't normally do this sort of thing.

I need to get in there to zip a folder and download it.

Please help?

Thanks
-O

Answer (score 0):

SSH -i /loc/xyz.pem username@ipaddress

Enter password for the pem file on getting prompted.

For downloading a file, it's as simple as doing(from local system)

SCP -i /loc/xyz.pem username@ipaddress:/serverloc/file.zip /localaddress/